# Vou criar um select e gostaria que ele atualizasse a quantidade de registros

Tags: php, html, select

Estou criando um sistema e na parte de registro de produtos em php a um select com a opção de quantos produtos vão ser registrados, gostaria q ao escolher o select atualizasse para aparecer o numero de linhas para registro, como posso proceder????

Gratidão =D

Comment: Bem-vindo, você pode começar fazendo [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e para obter respostas que solucionem sua dúvida / problema leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e [Como formatar minhas publicações usando o Markdown ou HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor forma é criando os campos dinamicamente através de javascript. Quando o usuário selecionar o número de produtos que serão registrados, você dispara o evento que criará os campos:

https://jsfiddle.net/caiubyfreitas/9cezx9wr/

Observe que os campos serão aninhados na DIV identificada por "container":

```
var container = document.getElementById("container")
```